# How to generate positive and negative power supplies from a single supply with high current driving capability?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, transceiver, lvds, buck-boost, negative-voltage

I am trying to build a 1553 military standard bus transceiver (analog front end) and I am required to use a single power supply of 3.3 V. To be able to receive, my comparators need supplies of +/- 3.3-10 V to generate the right CMOS logic levels. To transmit, I need even higher voltage supplies for current feedback drivers to amplify 3.3 V logic levels to as high as 20 V peak to peak. I first thought of using a boost converter to first boost 3.3 V to 20 V, then use a rail splitter to get +/- 10 V. But the possible problem with that would be lower current drawn from 3.3 V supply which could be problem for current mode transmission.

What is the best way to distribute such supply levels from a single low supply voltage?

Plus any advise regarding 1553 analog front end bus transceiver implementation would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Your title mentions "high current driving capability" but your question never says what "high" means here.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I need currents close to 100mA for driving the isolation transformer.

Answer (score 1):

### MIL-STD-1553B

- 1Mbps Bi-Phase HDX on a 1:1.41 ratio transfomer isolated Twin-Ax bus
- Tx Vout= 18–27 Vpp
- Twin-Ax is 78 Ohms (60~85)
- Tx/Rx side has 58 Ohms on each leg. (=0.75 Zo)

It is possible to use a single or bipolar but lower current losses occur with bipolar supply.

There are several ways to generate with boost from 3V to +/- 14V You will need about 5W with 50% duty cycle.

The CT3231M is one such ASIC method but not cheap.
[image]

GJV289A is the Chinese equivalent of MIL-STD-1553.

Designing the supply requirements comes only after the precise design specs are given for environment, voltage, current, temp rise, ripple, cost etc.**

Comment: "There are several ways to generate with boost from 3V to +/- 14V You will need about 5W with 50% duty cycle." Thats more like what I need right now, what would be the best way to implement such circuit?

Comment: supply requirements comes only after the precise design specs are given for environment, voltage, current, temp rise, ripple, cost etc.

Comment: Voltage = 10V, Current = 150mA, temp rise = 85 degrees, ripple = 300mV, what I need here is a general approach. Thanks

Comment: By the way, I am using LT1210 for LINEAR AMP part of the above circuit. Do you recommend other type of amplification? LT1210 is a current feedback amplifier. My input is 0 to 3.3 V CMOS pulse.